# What formula does Apple use to calculate text and background color for events in Calendars?

Tags: ios, calendar

When events are displayed in the Apple Calendars, they use variations of the calendar color to display the event. To illustrate:

[image]

The calendar has a bright orange color (the color of the vertical bar on the left), the event background has higher saturation but also higher lightness. The text color is darker.

I have tried to somehow guess the formula but it seems quite complex with special cases for light and dark colours.

Note that some applications like Fantastical seem to mimic the Apple colours very well.

Comment: What do you mean by.. what formula? Do they not just probably check out good color blending designs?

Comment: Well. Whatever the color of the calendar you choose the background and text color of the events in iCal and Calendar app will be calculated somehow. I have managed to extract their procedure by hacking around the icloud.com website (for text color for example they check if a color is grey, too bright or too dark and have special cases for that, if not they convert it to HSV, remove 0.35 from the value, then they set the saturation to at least 0.5 and value to at least 0.1, this gives a darker color than the original). However icloud colors are lighter than macOS/iOS

Comment: In my example in the question the original color is bright orange (#FFA600) and the calculated text color is darker orange (#B6790E) and background is pale orange (#FBE6C9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have dug into the icloud.com code to get the information I needed. Here is a javascript version of the algorithm:

```
const colorTools = {
  light: {
    text: "#a8a8a8",
    background: "#f8f8f8"
  },
  dark: {
    text: "#000000",
    background: "#bababa"
  },
  backgrounds: {
    "#a2845e": "#e0d3c1"
  },
  isLight: function(h, s, v) {
    return v > 0.6 && s < 0.1
  },
  isDark: function(h, s, v) {
    return v < 0.3
  },
  isGray: function(h, s, v) {
    return s < 0.1
  },
  bgBrightness: function(h, s, v) {
    return Math.min(v * 1.5, 1)
  },
  toColorPart: function(c) {
    c > 255 && (c = 255);
    const t = c.toString(16);
    return c < 16 ? "0" + t : t
  },
  PARSE_COLOR_RGBRE: /^rgb\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)$/i,
  PARSE_COLOR_HEXRE: /^\#([0-9a-fA-F]{3}|[0-9a-fA-F]{6})$/,
  parseColor: function(color) {
    let result = "#";
    let m;
    if (m = this.PARSE_COLOR_RGBRE.exec(color)) {
      for (let t = 1; t <= 3; t++) { 
        result += this.toColorPart(Math.max(0, Math.min(255, parseInt(m[t], 0))));
      }
      return result;
    }
    if (m = this.PARSE_COLOR_HEXRE.exec(color)) {
      if (m[1].length == 3) {
        for (let t = 0; t < 3; t++) {
          result += m[1].charAt(t) + m[1].charAt(t);
        }
        return result
      }
      return "#" + m[1]
    }
    return '#000000';
  },
  expandColor: function(c) {
    let t, n, r, i;
    rgb = this.parseColor(c);
    if (rgb) {
      const r = parseInt(rgb.slice(1, 3), 16);
      const g = parseInt(rgb.slice(3, 5), 16);
      const b = parseInt(rgb.slice(5, 7), 16);
      return [r, g, b];
    }
  },
  convertHsvToHex: function(h, s, v) {
    const angle = h == 1 ? 0 : Math.floor(h * 6);
    const u = h == 1 ? 0 : h * 6 - angle;
    const a = v * (1 - s);
    const f = v * (1 - s * u);
    const l = v * (1 - s * (1 - u));
    const c = [
      [v, l, a],
      [f, v, a],
      [a, v, l],
      [a, f, v],
      [l, a, v],
      [v, a, f]
    ];
    const r = Math.round(255 * c[angle][0]);
    const g = Math.round(255 * c[angle][1]);
    const b = Math.round(255 * c[angle][2]);

    return this.parseColor("rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")")
  },
  convertHexToHsv: function(rgb) {
    const c = this.expandColor(rgb);

    const cmax = Math.max(Math.max(c[0], c[1]), c[2]);
    const cmin = Math.min(Math.min(c[0], c[1]), c[2]);

    const s = cmax === 0 ? 0 : 1 - cmin / cmax;
    const v = cmax / 255;
    let h;
    if (cmax == cmin) {
      h = 0
    } else if (cmax == c[0]) {
      h = (c[1] - c[2]) / (cmax - cmin) / 6;
    } else if (cmax == c[1]) {
      h = (c[2] - c[0]) / (cmax - cmin) / 6 + 1/3;
    } else {
      h = (c[0] - c[1]) / (cmax - cmin) / 6 + 2/3;
    }

    if (h < 0) {
      h += 1;
    } else if (h > 1) {
      h -= 1;
    }
    return [h, s, v];
  },
};


function computeTextColor(rgb) {
  const [h, s, v] = colorTools.convertHexToHsv(rgb);

  if (colorTools.isLight(h, s, v)) {
    return colorTools.light.text;
  } else if (colorTools.isDark(h, s, v)) {
    return colorTools.dark.text;
  } else {
    const rs = colorTools.isGray(h, s, v) ? 0 : Math.max(s, 0.5);
    const rv = v - 0.35;
    return colorTools.convertHsvToHex(h, rs, Math.max(rv, 0.3))
  }
}

function computeBackgroundColor(rgb) {
  if (colorTools.backgrounds[rgb]) {
    return colorTools.backgrounds[rgb];
  }

  const [h, s, v] = colorTools.convertHexToHsv(rgb);

  if (colorTools.isLight(h, s, v)) {
    return colorTools.light.background;
  } else if (colorTools.isDark(h, s, v)) {
    return colorTools.dark.background;
  } else {
    let rs = colorTools.isGray(h, s, v) ? 0 : s;
    return colorTools.convertHsvToHex(h, rs, colorTools.bgBrightness(h, s, v));
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one thing you can do.

1. Have a back ground view own your view controller on story board. This will have your main back ground color.
2. Then have the other view inside the view. So for example, let's put a UILable inside the view.
3. On Interface builder, set the UILabel background color to be transparent with an opacity of what ever you want. Just make sure the opacity is less than 100%.
4. Done. Simple open the color picker for the background view and slide it left to right to see the effect.

[image]

Comment: This enables me to have a lighter background (with black I could make it darker) but that is not the point. I need to know how to calculate the exact color of the background and text which Apple uses given a specific calendar color.

Comment: In that case you might have better luck with [sites like this](http://paletton.com/#uid=10b0u0kllllaFw0g0qFqFg0w0aF). Many of those exist where you can plan your color scheme. From there you can calculate a co-relation between the color you have chosen, and the matching scheme pattern. I don't think you will be able to find Apple's **exact** formula :/ . But that's just my guess